# 2D Homogeneous Transformation : Reflection vs Mirroring

Tags: matrices, transformation, homogeneous-spaces

I have two questions:

(1)  Is there any difference between the terms Reflection and Mirroring in 2D Transformation?

(2) What are their Transformation matrices with reference to an arbitrary line?

Comment: Unless you define the two words in (1), it's hard for anybody to answer your question.

Comment: @SammyBlack, if I knew the definitions, why would I ask here? I think my instructor is using the terms interchangeably.

Comment: A *reflection* could be defined one way and a *mirroring* could be defined some other way, and it could be a useful mathematical task to show that they are actually equivalent.

Comment: As far as I know, a *reflection* is a linear transformation with only eigenvalues $+1$ and $-1$.  The eigenspace for $\lambda = -1$ is one dimensional.  The eigenspace for $\lambda = +1$ (the "mirror") is an orthogonal $(n-1)$-dimensional complement.  (In $n=2$ dimensions, this "mirror" is also $1$-dimensional, as $2 - 1 = 1$.)